# Read empty cells from the table JTable into the array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I need to read data from the table `JTable`. The problem is that this table may contain empty cells. In this case the error message is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

How to avoid this error message?

```
mdArrivals = new QueryTableModelFS();

tbArrivals = new JTable(mdArrivals);

String STA = mdArrivals.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check it, Read object  `mdArrivals.getValueAt(i,1)` and after it check if not null call `toString`

```
Object value = mdArrivals.getValueAt(i,1);
if (value!=null)
{
    String sta = value.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String value= String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Btw: There is no `jTable1` in the question

Comment: 'value' gives you a string "null" than there is no nullPointerException occur so if you are using if, else or while statements or other any one than you can manage easily your code like ...if(value == "null"){do somthing}